# Reference for principal bundles and related concepts

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, principal-bundles, connections, equivariant-maps

I am looking for a good reference for fibre bundles on differential manifolds, Ehresmann connections, principal $G$-bundles and principal Ehresmann connections (the $G$-equivariant version of Ehresmann connections). Could anyone advise me on this? I have looked at the book *Fibre Bundles* by Hausmöller, but it isn't quite what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest:

- Kobayashi S., Nomizu K. - *Foundations of Differential Geometry*; Volume 1, Chapter 2 and Note 1; Volume 2, Chapter 9, Subsection 3 and Note 12.
- Kolář I., Michor P. W., Slovák J. - *Natural Operations in Differential Geometry*, Chapters 3 and 4;
- Spivak M. - *A comprehensive introduction to differential geometry*, Volume II, Chapter 8;

where only the third book is easy and intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but: Chapter 6 in *Loring Tu's* [*Differential Geometry: Connections, Curvature, and Characteristic Classes*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319550829) seems friendly enough, and well explained. I think sections §27 and §28 are what you're looking for.